# Loading a .jar onto the webpage without the user being able to access it

Tags: java, web-applications, jar

Kind of hard to explain in one line but my problem is essentially like this:

I made a java applet that I want to run on a web page that I packaged into a .jar file. I'm able to get the applet working fine using the <applet> tag but the problem is, if the user views the page source, they will see:

```
<applet archive="directory/program.jar">
```

Assuming .jar files can be easily opened and all the class files decompiled, all the user would have to do is go to www.url.com/directory/program.jar to download my .jar and they would have all my source code :(

So I'm wondering if there is either a way to protect my code/jar from being decompiled (other than obfuscation) or to use some kind of server-side script to feed the contents of the .jar directly to the browser from a server-side location not publically visible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually check to see if this situation would occur by going to such a site? I have never had that problem because my source folder is hidden automatically...

Comment: No one wants your source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fundamentally impossible.

Java applets run the client.
Anything that runs on the client can be disassembled and modified by a sufficiently advanced user.

You should move your sensitive logic to the server and invoke it using HTTP requests ( and remember that the user can use Fiddler).
While you're at it, you should probably replace your applet with HTML and Javascript.

Comment: So the best way would be to have a client side applet that just gets input, sends it to the server to be processed, and recieves the output?

Comment: Yes.  However, applets are (almost) dead; use raw HTML & JS instead.

Comment: You should do as much processing as possible (& secure) on the client for better UX and more responsiveness.

Comment: Wouldn't java be easier for making a game?

Comment: It depends what type of game.  Tic-tac-toe or hangman - JavaScript.  Minecraft - Java.  OTOH with the emergence of the the HTML 5 canvas, a lot more games might be written in JS/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is no effective way to block access to the source code of any page; for the page to be readable by browsers and search engines, the source code has to be accessible, and therefore can be viewed and/or copied. That's just how the web works. HTML is sent as a text document and interpreted client-side.

Disabling the right-click is little more than an annoyance, and it works sporadically in alternative browsers. Even if you succeed, the View Source option in the menu is always present. The viewer could also use a download tool such as [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/), or even get the page from the Google cache without visiting your site at all.

**Edit:** Oops! I misunderstood your question. You should follow @SLaks advice and *"move your sensitive logic to the server and invoke ot using HTTP requests ( and remember that the user can use Fiddler)."*

Answer (score 0):

Other than obfuscation or encryption, no--one way or the other, the browser will have access to the jar.

You might be able to create an applet that loads more functionality at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

While quantum mechanics do rule the universe, they have less of a grip on your code than you might suspect. You cannot both deploy code to the client browser and not deploy code to the client browser. You have the option of doing one or the other.

You can prevent direct browsing to your `.jar` file by locating it beneath the WEB-INF directory in your WAR file.  This will also prevent `<applet archive="directory/program.jar">` from working.

Once the jar is beneath the WEB-INF directory you will need something to feed the resource to the client browser; the Spring resources servlet is good for this (If you are using Java and Spring).  I feel confident that other such tools exist.  With the Sprint resours servlet, your would deploy your applet with something like this:  `<applet archive="resource/program.jar"`.

If you write your own resource distributor, you can add security to make it harder to get the jar file; perhaps add a header to your requests like `IRGud: <user_id here>` and fail any request that does not have that header (or acceptable contents in the header).